# Should().Contain() with equivalency options

Tags: c#, fluent-assertions

I am attempting to assert that a collection of `Claim`s contains an expected set of claims. The problem that I seem to be running into is that there's no way to check for a subset and supply my own equivalency options.

```
var expected = new[] {
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "joshdev"),
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, "test@test.com"),
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, "Josh"),
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Surname, "Perry"),
};

var identity = GetIdentity();
```

What I've tried...

```
identity.Claims.ShouldAllBeEquivalentTo(expected, options => options.Including(x => x.Type).Including(x => x.Value));
```

This fails if the identity's claims are not exactly the expected set, e.g. there are more than just those claims.

```
identity.Claims.Should().Contain(expected);
```

This fails because `Contain` simply uses the `object::Equals` method which the `Claim` type does not implement.

What I need is some way to do `Contain` but with the same equivalency options as `ShouldAllBeEquivalentTo` exposes. I thought perhaps `ShouldBeEquivalentTo` would be what I wanted, but that provides for asserting the collection object itself, not the items in the collection.

Comment: How do you define two `Claim`s to be equal?  All fields equal or just a set of "key" fields?

Comment: In this specific testcase "Equal" just means that the `Type` and `Value` properties are equal. (See the first assertion, `options.Including...`) Ideally I'd like to be able to provide equivalency options like `ShouldALlBeEquivalentTo` but have the semantics of `Contains`, or somehow specify something like an `IEqualityComparer<Claim>`.

Answer (score 3):

If you use [Shouldly](https://shouldly.readthedocs.io), you can use **ShouldAllBe** with **Contains**.

```
collection1 = {1, 2, 3, 4};
collection2 = {2, 4, 1, 3};

collection1.ShouldAllBe(item=>collection2.Contains(item)); // true
```

And finally, you can write an extension.

```
public static class ShouldlyIEnumerableExtensions
{
    public static void ShouldEquivalentTo<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, IEnumerable<T> equivalent)
    {
        list.ShouldAllBe(l => equivalent.Contains(l));
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

An optional parameter exists on **ShouldBe** method.

```cs
collection1.ShouldBe(collection2, ignoreOrder: true); // true
```

Comment: I've just found on [latest version](https://github.com/shouldly/shouldly/issues/340#issuecomment-166708101) that there is a parameter `bool ignoreOrder` on **ShouldBe** method.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is not yet possible in the current version. The extension points are there (see the [EquivalencyValidator](http://fluentassertions.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/ef5bc38e40d8#Main/FluentAssertions.Net35/Equivalency/EquivalencyValidator.cs) class), but the list of steps is currently private. Otherwise you could have replaced the [EnumerableEquivalencyStep](http://fluentassertions.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/ef5bc38e40d8#Main/FluentAssertions.Net35/Equivalency/EnumerableEquivalencyStep.cs) with your own implementation that provides the 'contains' behavior.